# How to decide between Entity API exportables and CTools exportables?

Tags: 7, entities, importing-exporting

I'm planning to add support for import/export/clone facilities in the D7 version of the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module, similar to the import/export/clone facilities in (e.g) the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). More specifically to also provide support for importing/exporting the configuration of ***`Goals`*** and ***`Tasks`***.

To find out how to do so, I looked at the (interesting) Community Documentation about "[Exportable configuration](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/exportable-configuration)". Part of what is included there is this:

> ... two proven and documented APIs exist in Drupal contrib that greatly facilitate the process.
>
> - **Entity API exportables**. If your data is an [entity type](http://drupal.org/node/1260694), you can use the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module to make your data exportable. ...
> - **CTools exportables**. CTools can be used to provide exportables support whether or not your data is an entity type. ...

Since ***`Goals`*** and ***`Tasks`*** are both entities, it seems that I'm lucky: I can pick either one. However these are my questions to actually decide about which one to select:

- Are there any pros/cons or dos/donts for using either of these APIs to create my exportables?
- Which of these APIs appear to be the most appropriate for what I want to achieve?